# Excel VBA - Reference a column in a ComboBox that may not be there

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ComboBox in an excel userform that has two Columns the first is hidden and contains the staff employee number the second column contains the staff name.

I generate an email from a userform with which I include the staff name

```
Me.cbName.Column(1)
```

which works perfectly, except that this is an optional field so when no staff member is selected it returns an error as `Column(1)` doesn't exist.

I tried to create the following function to get the value and return it as a string but it returns the same error.

```
Public Function GetStaffName(cb As MSForms.ComboBox) As String
  If IsError(cb.Column(1)) = True Then
    GetStaffName = cb.Value
  Else
    GetStaffName = cb.Column(1)
  End If
End Function
```

Has anyone got a work around to reference a combobox that may or may not have a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check Combobox `ListIndex` property against `-1○6 to see if any selection is made:

```
Public Function GetStaffName(cb As MSForms.ComboBox) As String
    If cb.ListIndex <> -1 Then GetStaffName = cb.Column(1)
End Function
```

if no selection is made then no action is taken so the function will return an empty string (which is the default value for a `String` variable)

Answer (score 0):

I managed a crude work around.

```
Public Function GetStaffName(cb As MSForms.ComboBox) As String
  On Error GoTo errhand:
  GetStaffName = cb.Column(1)
  Exit Function

errhand:
  GetStaffName = ""
End Function
```

Like I said, crude.  I'm sure there must be a better way.  If someone manages to find a better solution I'll make it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [column count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-columncount-property-access) property is some way of the cb?

Sorry, I can't test but something like?

```
Public Function GetStaffName(cb As MSForms.ComboBox) As String
  If not cb.ColumnCount = 2 then
    GetStaffName = cb.Value
  Else
    GetStaffName = cb.Column(1)
  End If
End Function
```